# Properties of permutation representation (copied from my note in class)

Tags: abstract-algebra

I tried to understand the class, but I couldn't.
So I would like to know what following notebook I wrote about permutation representation.

($\rho,\mathbb{C}[X]$)$\in{}Rep_\mathbb{C}(G)$

$\rho:G\to{}Aut\ C[X]\overset{\tilde{}}{-}GL_{|X|}(\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathbb{C}[X]=\mathbb{C}$-vector space of dim $|X|$

Lemma
Let $(V,+,\cdot)$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space of dim $n$, if we fix a basis $\mathscr{B}$ for $V$,

Then $\exists$ a group isomorphism $\overset{\mathscr{f}}{\mathscr{B}}:$ Aut($V$)$\to{}GL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$

\begin{equation}
 \rho{}:G\to{}GL\\
  g\to{}[g]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  [g]:\mathbb{C}\to{}\mathbb{C}[X]\\
  x^{*}\mapsto{}g\cdot{}x^{*}
\end{equation}
$\quad(\text{following $x$ is } x^*)(\text{I couldn't add both * and number, sorry})$

Mat([g])=
\begin{matrix}
g\cdot{}x_1 \cdots{}g\cdot{}x_n 
\end{matrix}

\begin{pmatrix}
& \cdots& \\
& \cdots&\\
\end{pmatrix}
$n \times n$ matrix and each column is a coordinate?

g$\cdot{}x_1(x_j)=x_i(g^{-1}x_j)\quad{}(\text{by def of G-action on }\mathbb{C}[X])=\text{if } g^{-1}x_j=x_i \text{ then } 1;\text{ otherwise 0.}$

\begin{matrix}
g\cdot{}x_1 \cdots{}g\cdot{}x_n 
\end{matrix}

\begin{pmatrix}
0& \cdots& \\
\vdots& \cdots& \\
0& \cdots& \\
1& \cdots&\\
0& \cdots& \\
\vdots& \cdots& \\
0& \cdots& \\
\end{pmatrix}
element where value is 1 is $j_{th}$ row

$j$ s.t. $g\cdot{}x_1=x_j$ and j s.t. $g\cdot{}x_i=x_j$

$\Rightarrow1 \text{the diagonal of }[g]=1 \Leftrightarrow{} gx_i=x_i$

your sincerely

Comment: Surely the Lemma is just (part of) the standard fact that the algebra of linear transformations on aa vector space is isomorphic to the algebra of matrices of the right size, and that we get the isomorphism by choosing a basis. The rest just says that if a linear transformation permutes a basis then its matrix has has a single $1$ in each column, and so the non-zero elements on the diagonal occur at the fixed points of $g$. (This lets us work out the trace later.)  Precisely which bit of your notes do you not understand?

Comment: Thank you for replying!!!

To be honest, firstly what ($\rho,\mathbb{C}[X]$)$\in{}Rep_\mathbb{C}(G)$ and \rho{}$:G\to{}Aut\ C[X]$ mean?


I think I know \rho is representations of G on $\mathbb{C}$ But $\to{}$Aut C[X]?


Next I couldn't imagine $Aut\ C[X]\overset{\tilde{}}{-}GL_{|X|}(\mathbb{C})$. In other words, what should I imagine when isomophism exists between a map and matrix?


Next $\mathbb{C}$-vector space of dim $|X|$ of dim $|X|$? what to imagine from this sentense?


Next "we fix a basis $\mathscr{B}$ for $V$," fix a basis for a set?

Comment: Next "Then $\exists$ a group isomorphism $\overset{\mathscr{f}}{\mathscr{B}}:$ Aut($V$)$\to{}GL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$"
what dose it mean? does it mean "get the isomorphism by choosing a basis. "?


Next what is [g] ?


\begin{equation}

 \rho{}:G\to{}GL\\

  g\to{}[g]

\end{equation}
\begin{equation}

 [g]:\mathbb{C}\to{}\mathbb{C}[X]\\

 x\mapsto{}g\cdot{}x

\end{equation}

In the former [g] is a element of matrix GL(I don't have a confident). But in the latter [g] is a map. what is [g]?

Comment: Next why $x^{*}\mapsto{}g\cdot{}x^{*}$? why does G-action suddnly appear?

As a result, I can't connect your answer with content of notebook.

Next what does "n×n matrix and each column is a coordinate" mean?
why $g\cdot{}x_i$ becomes a coordinate in each of column of matrix?

Next how to consider $G\text{-action on }\mathbb{C}[X]$?(g$\cdot{}x_1(x_j)=x_i(g^{-1}x_j)\quad{}(\text{by def of G-action on }\mathbb{C}[X])=\text{if } g^{-1}x_j=x_i \text{ then } 1;\text{ otherwise 0.}$)

Comment: Next you tell me " if a linear transformation permutes a basis then its matrix has has a single 1 in each column, and so the non-zero elements on the diagonal occur at the fixed points of g." does that mean it can be 
\begin{pmatrix}
1& \cdots&0 \\
0& \ddots&0\\
0&\cdots&1
\end{pmatrix}
?

And I can't connect this topic and " \text{the diagonal of }[g]=1 \Leftrightarrow{} gx_i=x_i$"

I would appriciate if you would reply.
I was wondering if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think your notes are hopelessly confused.

Here is what I think is going on.

(i) Let $G$ be a finite group and $V$ a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space. Then we write $(\rho, V)\in Rep_\mathbb{C}(G)$ to mean that $\rho$ is a group homomorphism $\rho:G\to Aut_\mathbb{C}(V)$.

(ii) Recall that $Aut_\mathbb{C}(V)$ is isomorphic the the matrix group $GL_{\dim V}(\mathbb{C})$. This is justified by the following:

*Lemma* For each basis $\mathcal {B}$ of $V$ we have an isomorphism $f_\mathcal{B}:
Aut_\mathbb{C}(V)\to GL_{\dim V}(\mathbb{C})$. [For proof see any linear algebra textbook.]

(iii) Now let $G$ act on a finite set $x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n$. We form a vector space $V$ consisting of all $\sum c_i x_i$. Then if we set $\rho(g): \sum c_i x_i\mapsto 
\sum c_i (g\cdot x_i)$ we can check that $(\rho, V)\in Rep_\mathbb{C}(G)$.

(iv) We can now ask what the matrix of $\rho(g)$ is with respect to the basis $x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n$. Well $\rho(g)x_i=(g\cdot x_i)$. That is (by the definition of matrix) the $i$th column of of $[\rho(g)]$ is a column of $0$s, with a $1$ at the place $j$ determined by $g\cdot x_i=x_j$.

(v) We can then ask about the diagonal elements of $[\rho(g)]$. Each of these will be $0$ if $g\cdot x_i\ne x_i$, and $1$ if $g\cdot x_i=x_i$.

(vi) Hence $trace([\rho(g)])=$ the number of fixed points of the element $g$ on the set $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$.

**Note** It's usual to suppress the $\rho$ and just treat the elements of $G$ as automorphisms of $V$, or even just as elements of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ which is what your notes seem to do.

**Note** The notation $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is very very confusing since $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is used all over the place to mean the set of polynomial is a variable $X$, so I have not used it.

Comment: The notation $\mathbb C[X]$ is reasonably commonplace I think, where it is to be taken to mean $\{f\colon X \to \mathbb C\}$ the space of $\mathbb C$-valued functions on $X$. Since $X$ is finite, the natural induced action on $G$ on $\mathbb C[X]$ is the same thing as the linearization of the permutation action of $G$ on $X$.

Comment: Thanks @krm2233. I'm sure you're right. It's when the set is $X$ that I find it confusing so I preferred just to avoid using it.

Comment: I completely see you point, and I am a little confused about why it *hasn't* confused me in the past. I think it is just the usual thing that context controls our expectations of notation, but given it is commonplace in algebraic geometry, you can easily imagine $\mathbb C[X]$, meaning the polynomial ring, rubbing shoulders with $\mathbb C[\mathbb A^1]$, the functions on the affine line, and so have $\mathbb C[\mathbb A^1]\cong \mathbb C[X]$, and then as long as there is a variety which has been called "$X$'' lying around, the potential for confusion seems enormous!